# TypeScript suporta uma implementação equivalente a trait?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, typescript, trait

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto usando o Ionic, e gostaria de organizar melhor minhas classes.

Abaixo deixo um exemplo de como eu faria com o PHP:

```
<?php

 trait comportamento {
         public function ficarTriste() {
         }

         public function ficarFeliz() {
         }
 }

 trait acao {
         public function falar($texto) {
                echo $texto;
         }

         public function olhar($endereco) {
                return file_get_contents($endereco);
         }
 }

 class serHumano {
      comportamento;
      acao;

      //o resto do código
 }

 $humano = new serHumano();
 $humano->ficarFeliz();
 $humano->falar('oooi');
```

Como eu poderia fazer algo assim usando o TypeScript, eu usei o PHP como exemplo pois é a linguagem que eu estou mais familiarizado. Se não me engano no C# isso se chama `partial`.

Obs: Não coloquei o PHP nas *tags* porque a pergunta não se trata do mesmo, eu apenas usei ele para demonstrar o que eu quero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que deseja usar [*mixin*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) que, em tese, deve ser até mais flexível do que *trait*. A [proposta de implementação de *trait*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/311) foi fechada porque o *mixin* deve resolver isto. Mas *mixin* não provê auto implementação que você deseja. Aí o único jeito é usar a classe ou interface, implementá-la, e se a implementação for complexa demais e quiser aproveitar o código deve fazer uma delegação para um método externo.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
class comportamento {
    public ficarTriste() {}
    public ficarFeliz() {}
 }

 class acao {
    public falar(texto) {
        console.log(texto);
    }
    public olhar(endereco) {
        return console.log(endereco);
    }
 }

 class serHumano implements comportamento, acao {
    public ficarTriste() {}
    public ficarFeliz() {}
     public falar(texto) {
        console.log(texto);
    }
    public olhar(endereco) {
        return console.log(endereco);
    }
}
```

Veja ["funcionando" no **Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20comportamento%20%7B%0D%0A%20public%20ficarTriste()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20public%20ficarFeliz()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20class%20acao%20%7B%0D%0A%20public%20falar(texto)%20%7B%0D%0A%20console.log(texto)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09public%20olhar(endereco)%20%7B%0D%0A%20return%20console.log(endereco)%3B%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20class%20serHumano%20implements%20comportamento%2C%20acao%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20ficarTriste()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20public%20ficarFeliz()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20public%20falar(texto)%20%7B%0D%0A%20console.log(texto)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09public%20olhar(endereco)%20%7B%0D%0A%20return%20console.log(endereco)%3B%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fpt.stackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F216029%2F101). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Mixin.ts).

Fora isso dá pra fazer gambiarra que não recomendo.

Dependendo do que precisa pode se achar uma outra solução.

Se eu achar alguma outra solução eu posto aqui.

`partial` do C# nada tem a ver com isso. Existe uma [proposta para implementação de algo próximo ao *trait* nas próximas versões do C#](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/288).

Comment: então @bigown mas eu não gostaria de implementar esses métodos em cada classe... eles serão o mesmo para todos as classes. O problema é que vai ter muitos métodos e eu não conseguiria extender mais de uma classe entende?

Comment: Eu entendo, mas a linguagem não entende. Tem como fazer um serviço de delegação, mas com esse exemplo, nem compensa.

Comment: Entendi, então digamos que o TypeScript não permite que eu faça isso. É isso? Se for é só atualizar a resposta que marco como correta.

Comment: @HiagoSouza mais ou menos já estava, só dei uma melhorada