# Traits e mixins, o que são? Quando devo usá-los? Existem mecanismos semelhantes em outras linguagens?

Tags: terminologia, trait, mixin

Estava curiosamente pesquisando sobre [trait](/questions/tagged/trait) aqui no SOpt e percebi que ela está quase sempre associada a [php](/questions/tagged/php). Mas infelizmente a pesquisa não me rendeu uma resposta definitiva para o conceito de **trait**, apenas como usá-lo.

A única pergunta marcado com trait, mas sem a tag php foi: [TypeScript suporta uma implementação equivalente a trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216029/64969) ; [na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216046/64969), o autor da resposta falou sobre mixins, que atenderia o caso do AP.

Então, me surgiram as dúvidas:

- O que é um *trait*?
- O que é um *mixin*?
- Quais são os casos onde devemos usá-los? Quais os problemas de desenvolvimento/manutenção esses mecanismos propõe resolver?
- Em outras linguagens, existem outros mecanismos que resolvem problemas semelhantes?

Comment: Relacionado: [Quando devo usar herança, classe abstrata, interface ou trait](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73449/)

Comment: Relacionado: [Como usar Traits em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219197)

Comment: Acho que é meio amplo, até `less` menciona mixin: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença entre mixins e herança?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275897/qual-é-a-diferença-entre-mixins-e-herança)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cada linguagem implementou e chamou de *trait* o que bem entendeu. É uma dessas coisas que ninguém sabe definir ao certo.

Tanto *trait* como [*mixin*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275897/101) são técnicas de reúso de código, ambos fazem subclasse, sendo que o primeiro estabelece uma relação de subtipo e o segundo não, embora já vi caso que estabelece, então não sei se deixou de ser *mixin*.

O *trait* não possui estado, o *mixin* pode ter, mas já vi algo sendo chamado de *trait* aceitando estado e outro chamado *mixin* que não aceita.

Se o *mixin* tem estado e faz subtipo o que ele é diferente da [classe abstrata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101)? Talvez o fato de não permitir um construtor, só a classe concreta teria o construtor, a classe abstrata não pode ser instanciada mas pode ter construtor que obviamente só pode ser chamado pela classe derivada. Talvez seja isso mesmo.

Alguns dirão que colocar só implementação e até ter estado é apenas uma inclusão, que é um mecanismo "*sub-julgado*".

> Quais são os casos onde devemos usá-los? Quais os problemas de desenvolvimento/manutenção esses mecanismos propõe resolver?

É tudo uma questão de organização e reúso resolvendo os problemas que outros mecanismos possuem.

Herança de estado, principalmente, é complicada e lida com detalhe de implementação, além do que é comum um objeto ter coisas a fazer em comum com outros objetos, mas não ser uma herança como conhecemos normalmente. O *trait* resolve isso. O que um objeto é capaz de fazer é diferente dele **ser** derivado de algo.

Herança só de implementação desobriga o objeto ter um contrato mantendo a implementação.

Quando você entende todos os aspectos dos mecanismos, vê que pode ter uma intersecção de conceitos, nem todos precisam estar presentes, e quando isso acontece vai criando mecanismos derivados, por isso existem tantos. Tem linguagem que preferiu ter "um" bem flexível que permitisse fazer as derivações de acordo com o uso.

Linguagens de tipagem dinâmica conseguem fazer *mixin* mais facilmente, por não precisar do subtipo para funcionar, já que a vinculação do método ao objeto pode ser feita em tempo de execução, muitas vezes é o que o pessoal chama de [*duck typing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/574146/101), que pode ser ou não.

*Trait* costuma ser mais interessante em tipagem estática.

> Em outras linguagens, existem outros mecanismos que resolvem problemas semelhantes?

Sim, mas não só as linguagens dão esses nomes para mecanismos que nem sempre fazem isto, também fazem exatamente ou quase isto com [outros nomes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121240/101), ou sem dar nome direto ao mecanismo ([herança privada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/101), por exemplo).

Claro que [interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101) e classes abstratas são conceitos semelhantes, mas não idênticos. Também tem os [protolocos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50526/101), [delegações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87521/101), [políticas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design), [papéis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-oriented_programming), [conceitos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), [classes de tipos](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html), só pra ficar nos que eu lembro e sei.

## Conclusão

Tenho estudado isso, mas talvez porque as linguagens não os usavam anteriormente tenha pouca informação confiável, e o que tem é discrepante. Mas sei que são mecanismos poderosos e deveriam ser mais usados.

Eu acho engraçado PHP ter *trait* :) Interface também, classe ainda vai.

Note que nem tudo é o que diz ser:

- [Trait em D](https://dlang.org/spec/traits.html)
- [Mixin em D](https://dlang.org/articles/mixin.html)
- [Outra forma adotada em D](https://dlang.org/spec/template-mixin.html)
- [Trait em Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/traits.html)
- [Mixin em Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/mixin-class-composition.html)
- [Trait em Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/traits.html)
- [Protocolo em Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)
- [Método de extensão em C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)
- [Método padrão em Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)
- [Trait em PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)
- [Módulo em Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html)
- [Interface em Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html)
- [Delegação em Kotlin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221905/101)
- [Trait na biblioteca de JavaScript](https://traitsjs.github.io/traits.js-website/)
- [Papel de Perl](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/04/the-why-of-perl-roles.html)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O assunto é ainda mais extenso do que eu imaginava. E eu pensando que iria fugir mais ainda do conceito de delegações e protocolos

Comment: É verdade que traits e mixins são implementados em cada linguagem da maneira que eles bem entenderam, mas se for levar para um lado mais acadêmico, o melhor artigo que eu li e explica traits é este aqui: http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha02bTraits.pdf

Comment: E no caso, traits, conforme proposto, não usam do mecanismo de subclasse, eles sempre efetuam um flatten dos comportamentos para a classe onde ele "importa" as funções, e as traits possuem 4 mecanismos para tratar cenários de composição entre traits e colisão de comportamentos.

Comment: Nessa questão do Quora a Quildreen Motta resume bastante o artigo, de uma maneira simples, o que seria uma trait: https://www.quora.com/Are-Java-8-default-methods-equivalent-to-traits

Comment: Nota-se que traits em PHP por exemplo possuem o mecanismo de aliasing para resolução de conflitos no flatten das traits.