# Quais são as diferenças entre Traits (ou Typeclasses) e Interfaces?

Tags: terminologia, interface, rust, trait

Estudando Rust, comecei a fazer uso das chamadas traits que, de acordo com o livro da linguagem:

> Podemos utilizar traits para definir comportamento compartilhado de um modo abstrato.

O mesmo [capítulo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-02-traits.html) ainda cita o seguinte:

> Note que traits são similares a um recurso chamado interfaces em outras linguagens. Apesar disso, existem algumas diferenças.

Apenas para fim de desambiguação (já que o termo *trait* é bem comum na área), devo dizer que o conceito de traits do Rust foram inspiradas nas *typeclasses* de Haskell, então parecem ser dois nomes diferentes para algo bem similar.

Vindo de uma linguagem como TypeScript, não pude deixar de notar que realmente há certa semelhança com o conceito de interfaces, que também existem em linguagens como C# e Java.

- Visto isso, gostaria de saber, pontualmente, quais são as principais diferenças entre traits do Rust e interfaces (como as do TypeScript).
- Existem vantagens e/ou desvantagens associadas a cada um deles?

Comment: esse conceito de "trait" pode não ser bem universal, só vi esse conceito de `typeclass` ai no rails e outras linguagens (eu mesmo não conhecia :) ), por exemplo em testes ele descreve as características dos testes (aliás, a tradução de trais é "características"), pode ver aqui: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/part-2using-traits-with-different-test-frameworks-in-the-unit-test-explorer/ ou  https://github.com/brendanconnolly/Xunit.Categories

Comment: @RicardoPontual, eu sei que é um termo amplo, mas eu elaborei a pergunta limitando seu significado à forma como é utilizado em Rust (mecanismo esse que, como ressaltei, é similar às typeclasses de Haskell). Sobre a pergunta, não me parece ter tanta ambiguidade assim, então não sei se uma edição para limitar mais ainda venha a ser necessária. Mas acho que não tem nada a ver com o que você linkou – não posso afirmar com certeza, todavia.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279252/112052

Comment: @LuizFelipe sim, sua pergunta está bem contextualizada, só comentei pq eu já tinha ouvido o termo em outro contexto além de testes mas não conhecia, e coloquei no comentário para referência. Agora a pergunta que o hkotsubo relacionou me parece se tratar basicamente o mesmo não?

Comment: Diria que não, @RicardoPontual, acho que esta é um pouco mais específica.

Comment: Tive uma dúvida similar e encontrei uma resposta que achei bem completa, só que está em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477460

Answer (score 1):

De forma geral, quando comparamos um *trait* do Rust com uma *interface* do Java, notamos algumas diferenças como

- Em Rust, um *trait* pode definir métodos, tipos e constantes, mas não propriedades mutáveis.
- *trait* permite declarar tantos métodos para o objeto, quanto para a classe (estáticos).
- É possível implementar os métodos declarados diretamente no *trait*, de forma similar a uma classe abstrata.
- Você pode implementar um *trait* para uma *stuct* fora do módulo onde a estrutura foi declarada.
- Também é possível implementar um *trait* para os tipos definidos pela linguagem (*i32*, *String*, *Vec*)
- Você pode implementar o *trait* para estruturas com *generics* específicos, como por exemplo, implementar apenas para *Vec<i32>*, e não para *Vec<f64>*.
- Quando a linguagem não conseguir inferir, é necessário anotar se a estrutura implementa o *trait* com ligação dinâmica (dyn) ou estática (impl), mas isso é mais uma característica da linguagem do que do *trait*.